# can't select element with dom, after creating that element with other function - appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

How i'm supposed to select my element that have been created by function. First function is working well, but while i'm trying to select the element that been created in that function, it doesn't work

```js
let d = document.querySelector(".lop");
let body = document.querySelector(".body");

d.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let c = document.createElement("p");
  c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("lopas"));
  body.appendChild(c);
});

document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("Hi");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="lop">s</div>
    <div class="body"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate many times over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are attempting to attach a `click` event to your `paragraph` tag before its ever been added to the DOM.

You will need to move this new event listener inside of your onclick and *after* you append it to your `.body` div.

Example:

```js
let d = document.querySelector(".lop");
let body = document.querySelector(".body");

d.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let c = document.createElement("p");
  c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("lopas"));
  body.appendChild(c);


  document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Hi");
  });
});
```

As requested, here is how you could just split some of this out to be its own methods for clarity.  Feel free to use your own style as its just an example:

```js
const onClickLop = (e) => {
  const el = document.createElement("p");
  const bodyDiv = document.querySelector(".body");

  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("lopas"));
  bodyDiv.appendChild(el);


  el.addEventListener("click", onClickLopas);
};

const onClickLopas = (e) => {
    console.log("Hi");
});


document.querySelector(".lop").addEventListener("click", onClickLop);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to change that function inside to callback function? Just to make my code more readable. Cause when i put multiple of that functions inside one function, it's a big mess in my code

Comment: sure.   every time you see `function` being passed in as a parameter, you can easily split that out into its own function declaration.  I'll add an example of this as well.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

- You create the p element at the moment when you click on `.lop`
- You try to add the event listener at the page load. At this point there is no `p` tag at all.

**Solution:**

- Add the event listener after you created the p tag.
- You could also use the reference `c` instead of querySelector.

```js
let d = document.querySelector(".lop");
let body = document.querySelector(".body");

d.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let c = document.createElement("p");
  c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("lopas"));
  body.appendChild(c);

  c.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Hi");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="lop">s</div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need to query the document for the element that you already have in a variable `c`. Also if user clicks twice a second `<p>` is inserted that won;t be found using `querySelector()`

Answer (score 0):

The code to add the event listener for the `p` element is executing before your code that creates it. Move the event handler into the first function so that it isn't triggered until the element is created and added to the document. However, that will mean that each time you click the first element, a new `p` will be created with its own handler (separate question/answer).

Also, by doing that you can consolidate some code.

```js
let d = document.querySelector(".lop");
let body = document.querySelector(".body");

d.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let c = document.createElement("p");
  c.appendChild(document.createTextNode("lopas"));
 
  c.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Hi");
  });
  
  body.appendChild(c);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="lop">s</div>
    <div class="body"></div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doubles listener on first `<p>` and no listener on second when click twice

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but that is not what the question is about. I'm updating the answer to point some other issues out.